# D_FILE already defined in /home/staneppsjr/public_html/wp-config.php on line 82

Tags: errors

( D_FILE already defined in /home/staneppsjr/public_html/wp-config.php on line 82 )

I am not by any means a developer but I am trying my hardest to learn and work on my own websites.

This "error code" sits at the top of my website ( www.eppsfinancial.com )

1. I have contacted wordpress and they say it's my "builder plugin"
2. I have contacted "beaver builder" went in with temp access and said it is wordpress.
3. I contacted my hosting at "godaddy" and they said it was wordpress

I NEED SOME HELP I have spend WEEKS trying to solve this problem and NO LUCK...

The only thing I know is that when I delete my beaver builder plugin it goes away. BUT I NEED BEAVER BUILDER for now. I am still learning code.

(i have beaver builder on all of my websites and it does not do this on any other site)

[image: pic of my wordpress admin]
[image: [pic of ABOVE my header on website]

Comment: You have to delete the line starting with `define(` in your `wp-config.php`. That's at least what the error message says.

Comment: In your wp-config.php file, on line 82, you must have a line that looks like this: `define( 'D_FILE', 'something' );`. What does it say? WordPress doesn't add a line like that to the config file, so it must be something your or someone working on your site has added.